# How can I burn a slideshow to a DVD in its present form in iPhoto 2011?

Tags: photos.app

Using iPhoto 2011. I was going to export my slideshow as a Quicktime movie, then burn it to DVD in iDVD.

However when I get 3/4 of the way through my 20 minute slide show presentation, the video goes white. I have figured out that the slideshow ends but the export keeps on going. I think it has something to do with the synchronization between music and photos.

My slideshow is approximately 22 minutes long, and I have a playlist of songs attached to the slideshow. The option to sync the pictures to the songs is checked. The slideshow works perfect in iPhoto. But my exported video is longer than the pictures.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried exporting the slideshow *without* the audio, then re-adding the audio manually in iMovie? This way, you can make sure they both end at the same time by cutting the audio out early. Then, you can burn that to DVD.

Comment: i have not, i can't beleive they dont have a way in iphoto to export the movie to a dvd straight exactly how it is?! i have iDVD

Comment: I find iDVD a tad unpredictable these days when you ask it to do anything other than put a single movie on a disk.  That may be a localized issue, but it's clearly not an app that's getting much active support...

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to export the slide show in video format and use the finder tool to burn it to the DVD.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Can you please add more information to your answer? How do you export the slideshow, and how would you burn the file to a DVD? Answers need to be a little more in depth, so as to provide a more helpful answer.